# iOS - How do you show animations in part of a UIView?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

[Alfred](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alfred/id447020280?mt=8) for iPhone has a cute, animated silver platter character that wiggles his mustache and does other things.

> [image: Imgur]

There's one sprite for the motionless character. Various animations are started as the user interacts with the app.

Assuming that they're using a `UIView` for the app, how is this done? Lots of animated GIFs? SVG animations? Cocos2D in a canvas or something? Lots of images and setting the `UIImageView` source?

Comment: animated gifs don't work inside an iPhone app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen this app.

Could possibly be `UIImageView` and the animationImages property

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *animationImages
```

> An array of UIImage objects to use for an animation.

It could be Quartz and Core Animation.

It could be Open GL ES.

Comment: I have a UK app store account, so no I can't.